# Mapbox Android - How to cluster or organize markers?

Tags: android, gps, cluster-computing, mapbox, markers

I am having trouble organizing my markers. I have a bunch of them, and the problem is that [there are so many markers close to each other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnQfR.jpg) Making it impossible to navigate using such polluted map.

Is there a way to cluster all those markers or any other way to make it less polluted? I have made a search around Mapbox's website, and thanks to a developer, I have found a way to implement such method, but any of those can be used with markers added within the map ( mapboxMap.addMarker() )

Example: 
[Data Clusters](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/create-style-clusters/).

Does anyone know how to organize such markers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Sem you could create a cluster of markers by using method setClusteringEnabled. I also faced same issue, this method is not supported in current mapbox sdk. I am using 4.0.

Comment: I have changed the SDK to 5.0, have you found any other way to work around with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Mapbox [plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-cluster). This lib has DefaultClusterRenderer.java class, you need to use it or implement ClusterRenderer.java interface, for drawing your own icons